# Google Maps(play Services:9.0.2) + Firebase(9.0.0) hanging

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, freeze

I'm trying to implement code that tracks friends using the following methodology:

1. Friend location is pushed to Firebase (continuously every 1 second).
2. Location is pulled in my device and displayed using Google Maps API

Item number 1 above worked fine till one month back, but suddenly the app started hanging.

Please suggest some ideas.Thanks a lot in advance.

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tracker"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
}
```

## Activity File

```
public class ReceiverMapsActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    String trackID = "";
    private Firebase curTrackID_FR;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location firebaseSenderLocation=null,curReceiverLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Step-1: Basic Initialization
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receiver_maps);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        //Step-2: Map Initialization
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        initilizeMap();

        //Step-3: Firebase Registration To get Friend's Info
        curTrackID_FR.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Map<String, String> latLngMap = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                if(latLngMap!=null && latLngMap.get("lat")!=null && latLngMap.get("lng")!=null) {
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latLngMap.get("lat"));
                    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(latLngMap.get("lng"));
                    Location curSenderLocation = new Location("SenderLocation");
                    firebaseSenderLocation=curSenderLocation;
                    curSenderLocation.setLatitude(lat);
                    curSenderLocation.setLongitude(lng);
                    updateMapMarker(curSenderLocation);
                }
                else{
                    //NULL value received
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean initilizeMap() {
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    Location myLocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();
                    if (myLocation != null) {
                        curReceiverLocation = myLocation;
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                }
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "initilizeMap():: GoogleMap NULL ");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void updateDistanceAndAddress(Location senderLocation, Location receiverLocation) {
        // Code to update Distance and Address
    }

    public void updateMapMarker(Location location) {
        try {
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16.5f)
            );
            googleMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                            .title("Shuttle-Location")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
            );
            updateDistanceAndAddress(location, curReceiverLocation);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            curReceiverLocation=location;
        }
        else{
            Log.i(TAG,"onLocationChanged()::  location NULL");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); // Update location every second
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
         && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) 
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
   }

   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: `curTrackID_FR` is not initialized before use.  This activity uses only the legacy Firebase SDK.  You are also including the new SDK, `firebase-database:9.0.0`.  Is it needed for other activities?  Not advisable to use both.

Comment: Play/Firebase version 9.0.2 is well over a year old.  Consider upgrading to the latest 11.0.2?  Definitely remove firebase-client-android.

Comment: i have commented step-by-step and figured out that issue is with "Updation of Text view for every second" to show Friend's Address Information.Can Someone please suggest some idea, whats the best way to update TextView which is above google maps continuously(for every  second)?

Comment: @all , thanks a lot for the help , finally with latest version and removal of firebase-client-android helped. Now another issue is :on Lock of mobile pushing data to firebase is getting stop after some time(around 10 minutes). Once on open of mobile lock, data-pushing is restarting again.Will anyone please suggest some way to make service, push data continously to firebase even if mobile is locked?